# Event/query optimization

Tags: mysql, events, query-optimization

I wrote this event that updates status every day.

```
CREATE EVENT check_reactivated_status_daily
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1 01 ' DAY_HOUR
    COMMENT 'Check end date of the reactivated ad and update status accordingly.'
    DO
        UPDATE crn_archive_reactivated
        SET status = 'expired'
        WHERE end_date < CURDATE();
```

I want to optimize that event so it retrieves only rows six months since inserted, not to query entire table so I wrote this event:

```
CREATE EVENT check_reactivated_status_daily
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1 01 ' DAY_HOUR
    COMMENT 'Check end date of the reactivated ad and update status accordingly.'
    DO
        UPDATE crn_archive_reactivated
        SET status = 'expired'
        WHERE end_date < CURDATE()
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), inserted) <= 180;
```

But then it occured to me that query has to go through the entire table anyway to determine which rows are older then 6 months.

Is there some way to determine which rows are older then X time (6 months in my case) without querying the entire table?

Other solution could be possibly using LIMIT, something like this;

```
CREATE EVENT check_reactivated_status_daily
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1 01 ' DAY_HOUR
    COMMENT 'Check end date of the reactivated ad and update status accordingly.'
    DO
        UPDATE crn_archive_reactivated
        SET status = 'expired'
        WHERE end_date < CURDATE()
        ORDER BY inserted DESC
        LIMIT 10000;
```

In theory, that way it would go through 10000 (about 6-7 month worth) newest inserted rows instead of entire table of almost 2 million rows and counting.

Comment: How about `AND inserted > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH` with index on `inserted`?

Comment: That could work.
Can I use ```AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), inserted) <= 180```, this syntax looks cleaner.

Comment: No, because the function needs to be evaluated for every record. The whole point is to compare the row data to a constant.

Comment: Some expressions can be indexed (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts), but expressions that use non-deterministic functions like CURDATE() are not allowed.